# instagram widget wordpress width not right on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, widget, instagram

I have an instagram plugin installed, which i have put in the footer of my blog. on a desktop version, it is perfectly fine, however, on a mobile version, the screen is smaller and all the images align under each other, instead of 6 images next to each other as on desktop.

**I would like to know, how can I make them 2 rows with 3 images on a mobile? where the 3 images together of each row take in 100% of the screen from left to right? with css?**

I can't give you the full style css of the instagram plugin because it has a built-in css. But I can copy certain css element from the *inspect element* and put `!important` behind it. I just don't know how to do that.

you can see it here --> http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be

**EDIT**

```css
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
#sb_instagram .sbi_col6 {
data-cols:3!important;
}
}
```

this is what i have now, it fixes that i got 3 images on each row, but the images arent square, and my images are cut, not resised

Comment: In [this file](http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/css/sb-instagram.min.css?ver=1.4.8) there are 2 media queries for 640px and 480px defining the width of `.sbi_item` at `width: 50%;` and `width: 100%;` - change both of those to `width: 33.3%`

Comment: this isn't working :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a CSS `@media` query to target mobile, and add the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  #sb_instagram.sbi_col_3 #sbi_images .sbi_item,
  #sb_instagram.sbi_col_4 #sbi_images .sbi_item,
  #sb_instagram.sbi_col_5 #sbi_images .sbi_item,
  #sb_instagram.sbi_col_6 #sbi_images .sbi_item {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
  #sb_instagram .sbi_photo img {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  #sb_instagram .sbi_photo {
    height: 33vw !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
  }
}
```

Obviously you may or may not need to end up using `!important` for everything. Adding the above CSS results in the following:

[image: Instagram Layout]

Obviously I've swapped out your personal photos for placeholders, but the rest is your code.